# Show number of characters in a string in Java script

Tags: javascript

```html
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" id="txt" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="btn">ver</button>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  var botao = document.getElementById('btn');
  var texto = document.getElementById('txt');


  botao.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var s = texto.legth;
    window.alert(`${s}`);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing the `n` in `length`.

Comment: Side note: Although people tend to think of `length` as "the number of characters" in a string, it's really the number of UTF-16 *code units*, which aren't always the same thing. Details in my blog post [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/) if you're interested (and/or Chapter 10 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues,

- `texto` is an input, so you need to access `.value` to get the value in that input.
- a spelling error on the `.length` property, you have `legth` (*missing the `n`*)

so

```
var s = texto.value.length;
```